# Using Django to pass text for Python processing and return response

Tags: python, json, django, text-parsing

I am new to Django and struggling with passing data back and forth.  My sandbox right now is trying to create a quick page with a textarea to take inputted JSON and then basically respond back with the output of that input run through `json.dumps(input, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))`.  So, return the same JSON, but print it prettily.

It seems like this is fairly straightforward if I want to just return the JSON, but I want to embed the result in another HTML page.  I've tried the below but the spacing seems to get stripped out.  If I use a print command for debugging while running `python manage.py runserver`, it still doesn't break out the lines and indents.

```
def pretty(request):
    form = InputForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        output = json.dumps(output, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
    else:
        output = "Not valid"

    return render(request, 'printer/pretty.html', {'results': output})
```

I've also tried using a custom filter, thinking the tabs/carriage returns would be part of `results`, but no luck there either.

I realize there are better approaches to this than using Django, but this is the sandbox project I've chosen for whatever reason.  I'm trying to understand if I could use Django as the structure around basically running user input against home-grown Python scripts and outputting the results to the browser within the framework of a nice-looking dashboard.

Is the above possible, both the specific of nicely formatting JSON and returning it back to the user, as well as running arbitrary Python scripts and sending back the output?  Any pointers towards resources or other ideas I should be thinking about would be appreciated.  I can't seem to find anything related to what I'm trying to accomplish, which makes me think this is an unusual/wrong way to use Django.

Comment: There's nothing unusual about the use case you describe, other than possible security implications. In terms of your specific problem, it's hard to diagnose based on this information. For one thing, there's a bug in the code above (`output = json.dumps(output...) ` rather than getting it from the form). Also, please show basic debugging information. What does `print(output)` look like? If that's fine, what is the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is with how HTML collapses whitespace. For me, running `json.dumps({'test_array': range(3)}, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))` generates the expected "pretty" output:

```
{
    "test_array": [
        0,
        1,
        2
    ]
}
```

If collapsing whitespace is indeed your issue, you can resolve it by wrapping `<pre>` tags around your results variable in the Django template like so:

```
<pre>{{ results }}</pre>
```

Comment: Hi Shane, thanks for the quick response.  I'm getting the same results with the <pre> tag.  I'm thinking the format stripping is happening before it gets to the client's HTML response.